# Pagination Custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

I have a custom post type called 'doel'.
I have made a page template to display all the doel items

In this page template I loop the 'doel' post type and after 6 of them, I want to have a pagination.
Only, the pagination does not appear.

I started browsing on the internet and it seemed to be a common problem after version wp version 3.4

I tried some solutions from this site and the wp forums but none of them helped.

For Example, what I tried was adjusting the loop, so the pagination would be IN the loop, OUT of the loop or between endwhile and endif.
Also I tried the wp pagenavi plugin and the original wp previous and next post links but none of them are working, so I think there is something wrong in my loop.

My code atm is:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'doel',
'posts_per_page' => 6,
'orderby'=> 'menu_order',
'paged'=>$paged
) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>


    <div class="doel">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array('class' => 'featuredimg')); ?></a>
        <img class="logodoel" src="<?php the_field('logo_doelen'); ?>" />
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></a></p>
        <a href="" class="doneerlink">Doneer nu</a>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?><br class="clear" /> 
<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replace the wp_pagenavi(); by

```
if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) 
{
    wp_pagenavi(array(  'query' => $loop) ); 
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work eighter, prints nothing :(

Comment: please try puting 'posts_per_page'='6' within quotes

Answer (score 1):

Your pagination call is in no way aware of your query, it cannot just know what you mean it to paginate.

You need to pass your query object to it:

```
<?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $loop ) ); ?>
```

See [using wp_pagenavi() with custom queries](http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/wpn-2-74.html) for details.

Comment: It is working now :) I used the code from the link you gave me and adjusted it a little bit :)

Comment: For people who are also looking for this, what worked for me was:

`<?php
$my_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 9, 'post_type' => 'doel', 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ) );

while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();  ?>
CONTENT
<?php endwhile;
wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $my_query ) );
wp_reset_postdata(); // avoid errors further down the page
?>`